# DataTemplate's binding gives the target an incorrect/unset/null value

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I would like to propagate `DataContext` upwards from a dynamically created `DataTemplate` hosted withing a `ContentControl` such as following one:

```
var myFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(controlTypeToDisplay);//= typeof(MyControl)
var dctxBinding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext.Dctx"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ContentControl), 1)
};
myFactory.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, dctxBinding);

return new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = myFactory };
```

However the result of such binding is `null` even though the DataContext is being set within `MyControl`'s constructor. DataContext of MyControl definitely is not set null further down the road, constructor is invoked before setter of `Dctx`. How can I fix the binding so that `MyControl`'s DataContext and `Dctx` property are always in sync?

---

Full minimal example of the issue (should display two "FooBar" TextBlocks if working correctly):

```
//MyControl.xaml
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
//MyControl.xaml.cs
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = "FooBar";
    this.DataContextChanged += MyControl_DataContextChanged;
}

private void MyControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An unexpected change");
}

//MainWindow.xaml
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding DataTemplate}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dctx, TargetNullValue='&lt;null&gt;'}" />
</StackPanel>

//MainWindow.xaml.cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Type controlTypeToDisplay = typeof(MyControl);
    public DataTemplate DataTemplate
    { get {/*see first listing*/ } }

    private object _dctx;
    public object Dctx
    {
        get { return _dctx; }
        set { _dctx = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: is there a specific reason to create data templates and define data bindings in code rather than in XAML?

Comment: @dymanoid the reason is being able to find and load controls that extend the default interface from a different assembly. The controls should be responsible for their `DataContexts` except the main app must be able to save/restore their state in main repository.

Comment: User controls should not create/use own data context. Instead, user controls should inherit or explicitly obtain the data context (e.g. via bindings) from the view they are used in.

Comment: @dymanoid the trouble start when you do not know what DataContext the controls might have. Unless you start big reflection mess that is (each control has custom Attribute with a Type of their DataContext factory, and whenever an exetension is selected, reflect their factory and re-build their datacontext), all the mess just to obtain one reference. Would you still consider it rather than propagating context upwards? (honest question)

Comment: This is off-topic for your question. But without having an example of this, I cannot tell you what I would consider.

Comment: @dymanoid say all information the `MainWindow` has is a field with type of control which should be displayed `Type controlType = typeof(MyControl)`. I would like the MainWindow instantiate corresponding UserControl (i.e. MyControl) and serialize its DataContext when a button on MainWindow is clicked (assume MainWindow has a Serialize(object o) method). Who intantiated its DataContext is not important for me but it needs to be created and only assembly containing MyControl knows how. Note that setting `DataContext` of `ContentControl` will result in `ContentTemplate` to be ignored.

Comment: @wondra: What do you expect to show up in the ContentControl in your example...? It's empty. And what is "controlTypeToDisplay" supposed to be?

Comment: @mm8 I would expect `MyControl` to be displayed with correct datacontext (= a textblock with "FooBar" Text), MainWindow pretends that it does not know which type of control should be displayed until runtime. I have modified the example recently to better reflect the intended usage (see commets above), might introduced an error you can still test on the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of the root element in the `ContentTemplate` of a `ContentControl` is the `ContentControl`'s `Content`. Bind the `Content` property to your `DataContext`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Dctx}" ContentTemplate="{Binding DataTemplate}"/>
```

You must also set the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` itself (or the parent window) somewhere, and add some visual element to the `DataTemplate`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DataTemplate DataTemplate
    {
        get {
            var myFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            myFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(".")); //bind to the DataContext
            return new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = myFactory };
        }
    }

    private object _dctx = new object(); //set the Dxtc property somewhere
    public object Dctx
    {
        get { return _dctx; }
        set { _dctx = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the exatra work debugging provided example, forgot the `DataContext = this;` in posted example (had it set relative source=self in xaml and omitted it when copying)

Comment: And what about the other parts of my answer...? Your DataTemplate makes no sense at all and you don't set either the Dctx source property nor the Content property of the ContentControl...

Comment: Does not seem to work - ContentControl's Conent is empty when its DataContext is set. (plus Dctx's value is not "FooBar" but thats just side effect)

Comment: Empty? So what did you set it to? It is what you set it to obviously. In my example it binds to the Dctx property of the DataContext and this property can be set to any object.

Comment: Well, that is the problem: only MyControl's assembly knows what MyControl's DataContext should be (for simplicity, lets just _pretend_ the control is defined in different assebly loaded in runtime). MainWindow just knows a type somebody passed to it. And all MainWindow should do is to render the control(which accidentaly happens to be MyControl containing TextBlock) of specified type and retrieve its DataContext (whatever it might be, whichever way it chooses to - example shows almost-function DataBinding). Would this clarify the question a bit? If not, feel free to ask further.